# I want to edit the first column of text file that i have stored in 2D array

Tags: c#

My code looks like this

```
using System.IO;

public partial class optionForm1 : Form
{
    const int ROWS = 20;
    const int COLS = 8, NUMBER =1, NAME=0;
    public const char SEPARATOR = '|';
    String[][] transactions = new String[ROWS][];
    int recordCount = 0;

    //User enters name they are looking for and clicks
    private void nameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS;  row++)
        {
            if (transactions[row][NAME].ToLower().Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < transactions[row].Length; col++)
                {
                    //currentRow = row;
                    transactionsListBox.Items.Add(transactions[row][col]);
                }
```

//I entered a different name "George Smith " in text box but it just adds it below existing line, but it does not replace the name

private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        foreach (var NAME in transactions)
        {
            transactionsListBox.Items.Add(editTextBox.Text);
        }
```

Keith Earls|128|120000|14|2.00%|€92.05|keith@gmail.com|19/03/2017 11:40:56|

George Smith

George Smith

Thank you for your patience

```
    }
```

Comment: The 1st loop within the button click doesn't make sense. Condition `row < recordCount` should this be `row < ROWS` because rowcount is initialised to 0?

Comment: Next the `NAME` constant doesn't look right ie you have it set to 1 but shouldn't it be 0 (arrays index's start at zero) - if NAME is 1 they you're referencing that number `128`

Comment: thank you for spotting that, doing a lot of changing on it                          
I am trying to something like this to edit it but sure

Comment: I am trying something like this to edit it but not sure

Comment: you could use linq to find the transaction row - something like this `var transaction = transactions.Where(t => t.Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();` then add to your list `foreach (var value in transaction) { transactionsListBox.Items.Add(value); }`

Comment: Personally I'd create a class to represent the transaction row and not use arrays or arrays...

Comment: help please eeeeeeeeeeee